# Does adding the content at the start of file result in updating all the data blocks?

Tags: files, inode

In the Unix File system (UFS), the file is represented as an inode structure which has 15 pointers that reference the direct blocks or indirect blocks.

Taking the below images is an example.

[image: Inode Structure]

Each block represented as `Data` on the right hand side contains the actual file data. And the size of this `data block` usually is 4096 and is decided during the file system creation.

For a huge file of 40 MB it would occupy nearly 1K data blocks. Given this scenario, if we append data to this file I see it would only impact the last block or if there is no space in the last data block it will create new data block.

But if we add some data (some 200 bytes) at the start of file, would it have cascade effect on the below data blocks and results in moving (or pushing) last 200 bytes of its each data block to the next data block?

Similarly when we delete the first 200 bytes from the first data block, will it have cascade effect on the lower data blocks?

Or is there an efficient way that UFS or in general file systems employ to handle such scenarios, may be some buffer space is reserved for each data block?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most filesystems don't support inserting data at the beginning of a file, and Unix doesn't have an API for that. In most operating systems, the only ways to modify a file are to overwrite a segment (e.g. change `aaaaaaaaaa` to `aaabbbaaaa`), to append data at the end (e.g. change `aaaaaaaaaa` to `aaaaaaaaaacccc`), or to truncate the file (e.g. change `aaaaaaaaaa` to `aaaaa`).

If you want to add data at the beginning of a file, create a new file with the additional data, and copy the content of the old file after that.

This is true both for the original Unix and for most if not all modern ones (and more generally for most operating systems).

Comment: @Giles Thanks for the response. I am not sure I got it `Most filesystems don't support inserting data at the beginning of a file`. Because let us say we have a filesystem with blocksize of 4 bytes and the file contents are `ABCDWXYZ`. Since the block size is 4 bytes 1st block will have `ABCD` and second will have `WXYZ`. Now if I add `123` to the start of file. It effectively becomes `123ABCDWXYZ` and we are able insert data at the beginning of file  Isn't it?So now the first block contains `123A`, 2nd one `BCDW` and 3rd one `XYZ`. I am new to Unix, sorry I it looks too basic a question.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu You can't insert data at the beginning of the file. You can only create a new file with blocks `123A`, `BCDW` and `XYZ`.

Comment: so in the above example when we inserted `123` in the existing file, it has resulted in creating 4 new blocks against this file and discarded the earlier 3 blocks? Or did I misinterpret your comment?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu No, it doesn't discard any block. You cannot insert data into an existing file. You have to create a new file, and then remove the old file.

Comment: Frankly, that is the point that I am not able to understand. You said `cannot insert data into an existing file`. But then when I added `123` into an existing text file, say `myfile.txt`, I see (or at least I have been thinking) that I have inserted data into existing file `myfile.txt`. I doubt I am interpreting your comment wrong, but could you help me understand that? Also, can you point me to any link or material that would help me in this context.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu You cannot add `123` into an existing file, except at the end. A program can create a new file, write `123`, then copy the content of the old file, and finally move the new file to the old name. A program can load the old file content into memory, truncate the file, write `123`, and write the content from memory. But a program cannot call the kernel and say “insert `123` at the beginning”, there is no such feature.

Comment: Thanks Gilles. I got it and that is making sense to me now. I would like to continue deep dive into this aspect further. Can you recommend any link or site where I can find more or subsequent information.

Comment: Just wanted to check if you have any link/article/tutorial handly where I can find more information or supporting information on this subject

Comment: Just a follow up question. Does the above answer hold true even for replacing characters in a file. I mean, say we have file that has initial content as `abc` and if I replace one of the character with other, say `a` with `1` and now the file contents become `1bc`. Will it still result in creating  a new file/blocks.?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu Replacing bytes in a file doesn't create a new file, it overwrites what was already there.